# C-h f issue , content not displaying until a second type

Tags: emacs

when I try to find help topic on a function C-h a , the content will not directly show up.
instead "Type "q" to delete this frame." will occur in the mini-buffer, then nothing show up. but if I type a second time, the content will show up

this is the case for the moment, not sure what configuration is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a year and a half since you posed the question, and still no answer. Here's my (partial) answer.

As always with such a problem, state your Emacs version and a recipe to reproduce the problem, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).  If you cannot repro the problem from `emacs -Q` then bisect your init file recursively until you find the culprit code.

If you can repro the problem from `emacs -Q` then people here will be able to help you understand whether it is the expected behavior or not. If not, `M-x report-emacs-bug` is in order.  Even if you are not sure whether something is a bug, you can use  `M-x report-emacs-bug` -- Emacs Dev will let you know.  But again, a bug report should preferably include a recipe starting from `emacs -Q`.